# custom field is not available for query in workbench

Tags: soql, salesforce-id, workbench

I have a custom multi-select picklist on opportunity object. When I'm trying to run a query on opportunity object using this field it's throwing an error, and this field is also not listed in the opportunity fields in workbench.

I've checked Field Level Security: Readonly permission is granted for my profile.

Comment: Please add the thrown error message to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the query you are running in Workbench? Take a read of the [Searchable Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_custom_object.htm&language=en_US&type=0) documentation by Salesforce where you will see multi-select picklists are not searchable.

Comment: If the field isn't showing up in the list of Opportunity fields to bring into the SOQL query then there is likely a problem with the permissions for the users profile.